# join 4 tables in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four main tables:

```
CREATE TABLE t_users (
user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
user_email varchar
);

CREATE TABLE t_items (
item_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
owner_id varchar not null references t_users(user_id),
title varchar
);
CREATE TABLE t_access_items_users (
access_iu_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
item_id varchar not null references t_items(item_id),
user_id varchar not null references t_users(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE t_friends (
friend_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
from_user_id varchar not null references t_users(user_id),
to_user_id varchar not null references t_users(user_id)
);
```

With data:

```
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us123', 'us123@email.com');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us456', 'us456@email.com');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us789', 'us789@email.com');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('public', 'public@email.com');

INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it123', 'us123', 'title1');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it456', 'us456', 'title2');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it678', 'us789', 'title3');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it323', 'us123', 'title4');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it764', 'us456', 'title5');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it826', 'us789', 'title6');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it568', 'us123', 'title7');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it038', 'us456', 'title8');
INSERT INTO t_items VALUES ('it728', 'us789', 'title9');

INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu123', 'it123', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu456', 'it456', 'us456');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu678', 'it678', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu323', 'it323', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu764', 'it764', 'us456');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu826', 'it826', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu568', 'it568', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu038', 'it038', 'us456');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu728', 'it728', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu728', 'it728', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('apu123', 'it678', 'public');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('apu222', 'it123', 'public');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('apu111', 'it456', 'public');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu333', 'it728', 'public');
INSERT INTO t_access_items_users VALUES ('aiu444', 'it826', 'public');

INSERT INTO t_friends VALUES ('f123', 'us123', 'us456');
```

Request for a type:

```
select *
from t_access_items_users
inner join t_items on t_access_items_users.item_id = t_items.item_id
inner join t_users on t_access_items_users.user_id = t_users.user_id
where t_access_items_users.user_id = 'public';
```

returns 5 rows.

Why the query type:

```
select 
t_items.item_id,
t_items.owner_id,
t_items.title
from t_access_items_users
inner join t_items on t_access_items_users.item_id = t_items.item_id
inner join t_friends on t_items.owner_id = t_friends.from_user_id
where t_friends.to_user_id = 'us456'
or t_access_items_users.user_id = 'public';
```

returns 4 rows?
How to make the right request to get all need rows?
Ultimately I want to get data where the items have access to the public and with the user's friends' friendships.
How to make a query returning all the elements that:

```
t_friends.to_user_id = 'us456'
or t_access_items_users.user_id = 'public'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your test data seems to be missing the data for t_friends.

Comment: It returns 4 rows because, t_friends contains 4 matching rows, if you want to return 5 rows, then you can replace inner join with left join with t_friends

Comment: @KKK is right thank you.

Comment: You can mark this question answered.

Comment: In addition to KKK comment use DISTINCT clause after SELECT. you will end up with 7 distinct item/ rows. That is because an item might be included twice evaluating to either of where condition.

Comment: @Mankind_008 Yes, thank you.